# Access JSON like object properties

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, lodash

I have a return object like so:

[image]

Can you tell me how to access its properties?

I have tried many ways with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) too. But no luck yet.

Failure attempts:

```
t.config['type']

 pick(t.config, 'type')
```

Comment: Deserialize it! `t.config = JSON.parse(T.config);` then `t.config.test`

Comment: Oh.. completely forgot about it. Please put it as an answer. Works fine now. @AluanHaddad Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `config` property is a serialized JSON string. You can work with it simply by deserializing it as follows

```
t.config = JSON.parse(T.config); 

console.log(t.config.test);
```

However, if you have any control over how the object `t` is provided to you, please (and I really mean please), fix and clean up that provider so you don't have nested, partially serialized objects. Otherwise, maintainability will suffer.

Comment: Yes, this is actually a one-time data retrieval from the old SQLite table. So no more maintains here after. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do...

```
const myResponse = JSON.parse(response.config);
console.log(myResponse.type);
```